# Is the stabilizer of an element $\delta$ in the stabilizer of $\omega$ in G equal to the pointwise stabilizer of $\{ \delta, \omega \}$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

i.e., is $(G_{\delta})_{\omega} = G_{( \{\delta, \omega\} )}$?

I know that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(G_{\delta})_{\omega} &=& \{ \forall g \in G_{\delta} \,|\, \omega^g = \omega \} \\
&=& \{ \forall g \in G \,|\, \delta^g = \delta, \, \omega^g = \omega \} \,\text{(is this correct?)} \\
&=& G_{(\{ \delta, \omega \})} 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that

- $G$ is acting on a set $\Omega$, to which $\delta$ and $\omega$ belong,
- $\delta \ne \omega$, and
- *$G_{(\{\delta, \omega\})}$ denotes the stabilizer of $\{\delta, \omega\}$ in the action of $G$ on the subsets of $\Omega$.*

Then, no, it is not true in general.

- Consider $G = S_{n}$ acting on $\Omega = \{1, 2, \dots, n \}$.
- Then $(G_{n-1})_{n}$ is $S_{n-2} \le S_{n}$.
- But $G_{(\{n-1, n \})}$ also contains the $2$-cycle $(n-1, n)$, and it is actually the direct product $S_{n-2} \times \langle (n-1, n) \rangle$.

For instance, when $n = 3$ you have $(G_{2})_{3} = \{ I \}$, where $I$ is the identity map, while $G_{(\{2, 3 \})} = \{ I, (23) \}$.

Comment: I suppose the distinction between the pointwise stabilizer of a set and the "setwise" stabilizer of a set is relevant, as the claim is true if $G_{\{\delta,\omega\}}$ is the pointwise stabilizer but not true if it's the setwise stabilizer.