# Notation for pointwise versus "setwise" stabilizers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, group-actions

Suppose one is working with both pointwise and setwise stabilizers of sets under a group action.

Are there common conventions for notationally distinguishing these two notions? How common are they? Is there a standard one? Any suggestions for how to write them? Pros and cons?

This comes in response to [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702476/is-the-stabilizer-of-an-element-delta-in-the-stabilizer-of-omega-in-g-equa), although I've been frustrated before by my lack of knowing a standard way to notationally differentiate these two.

Comment: If I had my way, (if $G$ acts on $X$) I'd let $G_S$ for subsets $S\subseteq X$ represent pointwise stabilizers and let $G_x$ for $x\in X$ be abuse-of-notation for $G_{\{x\}}$. There'd be an induced action of $G$ on ${\cal P}(X)$, in which case the pointwise stabilizer $G_{\{S\}}$ for the "point" $S\in{\cal P}(X)$ would be the setwise stabilizer of the original subset $S\subseteq X$. There'd also be an induced action of $G$ on the set-partitions of $X$, in which case we would have $(\cdots(G_{S_1})_{S_2}\cdots)_{S_n}=G_{\{S_1,S_2,\cdots,S_n\}}=G_\Sigma$ for the appropriate partion $\Sigma$.

Comment: I would say that there is unfortunately no consensus about this. For a subset $S$ of $X$, $G_S$ is sometimes used to denote the pointwise staiblizer (Wielandt used that notation, and it is what you prefer), and sometimes as the setwise stabiliser, which I prefer myself, because it should after all be denoting the stabilizer of the set $S$.